# »virtual template« hook into page-template-selection

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am about to create a Wordpress theme and I would like to know if it is possible to hook into the creation of the page template selection, so that I can add entries there.

In detail: If one creates a `*.php` file in the template directory and adds a comment like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: somename
 */
?>
```

than an entry in the page template selection drop down list appears. This requires a single File with such a comment for every desired entry. So here my question:

Can I hook into the process when this drop-down is, or was, or will be created to add Entries there?

Greetings
philipp

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do... Are you asking about "virtual" templates? PHP template files created on-the-fly and saved to disk? What's your end goal? ::: I'd dare to say that, no, there is no hook for this (searched through the core files).

Comment: »virtual template« that is the absolutely right term for what I would like to do.